# displaying prompt box from plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have a plugin that i would like to show a pop up where a user can enter some text, which when completed the plugin can use. Is such a thing possible or are prompts only available using javascript?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible. You can pass a message from a plugin to a user by throwing an exception, the user will get the exception message but they wont be able to reply.

I would suggest a dialog using custom workflow activities.

Comment: Thats what i thought, but never hurts to check. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done the way you think. That's because the plugin is run directly on the server. However, you've got two options.

1. If it's for debug, you can use a tracer and write to it. The downside is that you need to crash the plugin to deliver the message to the GUI. Hardly recommendable for a common user.
2. If you absolutely must (and I **know** you don't must **that** much), you could invoke a web service from the plugin. If the web service gets to communicate with the desktop *somehow*, you'll be able to start desktop-ish application and show the message box from there.

What would you like to achieve by the message box, by the way? Plugins are meant to handle the internal logic on the server so there might be a better approach to what you had in mind.